# Characterising elements of a reproducing kernel Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I am slightly puzzled by [Exercise 22](https://books.google.com/books?id=bX3TBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA54&dq=berlinet%20thomas-agnan%20coincides%20with&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q=berlinet%20thomas-agnan%20coincides%20with&f=false) in Berlinet, Thomas-Agnan. It states

> Prove that a function $f$ belongs to $\mathcal{H}_K$ if and only if there exists a constant $C$ such that for all $s$ and $t$ in $E$, $f(s)f(t)\leq C^2 K(s,t)$ and the minimum of such $C$ coincides with $|| f||_K$.

What is wrong with the following simple counterexample?

Let $E=\{1, 2\}$, $\mathcal{H}_K$ be $\mathbb{R}^2=\{f\,|f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ with $K(i,j)=\delta_{ij}$ the standard scalar product. Choose the function such that $f(1)=f(2)=1$. Then  $f\in\mathcal{H}_K$ but since $f(1)f(2)=1$ and $K(1,2)=<e_1,e_2>=0$ the required inequality cannot hold!?

Comment: Are you sure that $\mathcal{H}_K$ is defined the way you think?  Google won't let me look at the preview.

Comment: Hmm, of course I am not sure, something got to be wrong here. Nevertheless, I copied the complete text of the exercise verbatim and I think they generally use $\mathcal{H}_K$ for a generic RKHS. You definitely see the page by looking for "berlinet thomas-agnan coincides with" on Google books.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality should be taken as a kernel inequality, that is, there exist a
constant $C > 0$ such that $C^2K(s, t) - f(s)(t)$ is a kernel.

In your example $K$ would be the $2\times2$ identity matrix and
$f(s)f(t)$ would generate the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Taking, for example, $C = \sqrt2$, we obtain
$$
C^2K(s, t) - f(s)f(t) 
= \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
This is positive semi-definite since its sub-determinants are $1$ and $0$.
Moreover this is the least such $C$ therefore the norm of $f$ is $\sqrt2$, which
can also be computed directly.